# Kubectl wait command cannot be found

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am trying to use the kubectl wait command as outlined in the kubernetes docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait

When I run it, I am getting

```
Error: unknown command "wait" for "kubectl"
```

Docs do mention that the command is "experimental". Is there something I need to do to indicate I want to use experimental commands? All the other kubectl commands work fine.

I am using the kubectl command in windows, installed as a gcloud component. I have updated all components. kubectl version returns:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.7-gke.4", GitCommit:"618716cbb236fb7ca9cabd822b5947e298ad09f7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-05T19:22:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.7b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure in which version `kubectl wait` was introduced, but I have:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:08:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and it works for me:

```
~ kubectl wait --help
Experimental: Wait for a specific condition on one or many resources.
```

Update to the latest version and you will have it

Edit: the command was introduced in version [1.11](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.11.md). Here is the relevant [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/64034).

Comment: Thanks. Considering how often K8s changes are released you would think that the docs might mention the version that it applies to.